# text-decoration: none not working at all

Tags: html, css, text-decorations

I am trying to remove the underline on the text within my button div but cannot get anything to work, please advise how I can get rid of it.

Any help much appreciated.

**Code:**

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
#topbar {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6%;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px #888888;
}
#leftpane {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  height: 94%;
  background-color: #8b9dc3;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px #888888;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn {
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 2px 0px 2px 5px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn p {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="leftpane">


  <a href="url/post.php">
    <div class="btn">
      <p>Post a Bulletin</p>
    </div>
  </a>



</div>
```

I have tried various ways of implementing `text-decoration: none` but none have worked, that is why it is now in several places.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the text-decoration to none on the anchor (`#leftpane a`):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
#topbar {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6%;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px #888888;
}
#leftpane {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  height: 94%;
  background-color: #8b9dc3;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px #888888;
}
.btn {
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 2px 0px 2px 5px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#leftpane a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="leftpane">
  <a href="url/post.php">
    <div class="btn">
      <p>Post a Bulletin</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want to move your `text-decoration: none` into a separate statement

```
#leftpane a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

This is because "a" under there will have inherited its default styles, in order to override them, you have to be more specific at the tag level.

See the working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u9dupksp/)

Answer (score 1):

You need a more specific selector:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
#topbar {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6%;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px #888888;
}
#leftpane {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  height: 94%;
  background-color: #8b9dc3;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px #888888;
}
#leftpane a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn {
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 2px 0px 2px 5px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn p {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="leftpane">


  <a href="url/post.php">
    <div class="btn">
      <p>Post a Bulletin</p>
    </div>
  </a>



</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
#leftpane > a {
text-decoration:none
}
```

The [text-decoration property is not inherited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) so you need to specify it on the actual anchor element, not its parent.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add some explanation to your code: why does it works? What should it do?

Comment: <div id="leftpane">
<a href="url/post.php">Post a Bulletin</a>
</div>

Comment: asker should use this format of html in this case #leftpane should inherit to  anchor 'a' tag class

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

as pointed out, "!important" should be used to override inaccessible css rules, otherwise specificity is the way to go

```
-----
```

try

```
.btn:first-child {
      text-decoration: none !important;
 }
```

or

```
 #leftpane a {
     text-decoration: none !important;
 }
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your code snippet and additionally justify your use of `!important` which is generally an anti-pattern.

Comment: i read somewhere that "!important" can be used to override other css rules, my justification for the use of "!important" is that i use it to see if there are css rules already on an element, or the other way round, to make css rule exceptions, for example, in a text block with 10 paragraphs i might use the same css rules for all paragraphs elements except the first one, for example .c p {font: 12px Arial;} then .c p:first-child {font: 17px Arial !important;}

Comment: You don't need !important in your example since `.c p:first-child` is already more specific. You should generally avoid !important unless there's a very, very good reason to use it because if its high specificity http://james.padolsey.com/css/dont-use-important/

Comment: excellent advise! i will try and be more precise with CSS rules

Comment: Happy to help. Mind updating your answer for others?